# Report generate in Jsreport in nodejs application

Tags: node.js, angular, jsreport

all I have a question that I'm working on a project using Front-end Angular.js, Backend API using  Node.js project and MongoDB. I have to generate some report. I have found jsreport is a good option. now I install jsreport in my Node.js Application using this command 
`npm i -g jsreport-cli
jsreport init
jsreport configure
jsreport start`

Please note that I have made this jsreport in the same nodejs Project. My question is this a good practice or makes separate project since jsreport will use the different port.

Answer (score -1):

For my application it is a good practice to have separate instance for jsReport for scaling reason. Report rendering is a heavy process in jsReport, if it's on the same instance/port, it will use that process which should be used for application logic. I always have it separated so if I need to scale my reporting, i'll just spawn several report instance only and do load balance it. Docker and kubernetes can help you on scaling easily